# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^3+x^2}{{(x^4-1)}^3}dx$

Tags: calculus

Integral of $\int \frac{x^3}{{(x^4-1)}^3}dx$ is trivial so we are left with

$\int \frac{x^2}{{(x^4-1)}^3}dx$.

These integrals are usually done using substitution $x\pm\frac{1}{x}=t$ after we add and subtract $1$, but I can't do it that way since there is subtraction in the denominator.
Of course, I could do it using partial fractions but that seems like a never ending brute force approach.

Any tips?

Comment: Yes, that is why I wrote that that part is trivial

Comment: Given [the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E2%2F%28x%5E4-1%29%5E3), I think partial fractions are unavoidable.

Comment: Fastest way to compute it would be probably the Residue Theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem . However some complex analysis theory is needed to apply it, I don't know if it is a practical solution for you.

Comment: This is about computing a primitive, not an integral on a given domain. I don't think you can apply the Residue Theorem. Partial fractions are the way to go.

Comment: If the question is about computing primitives, then the residue Theorem is of no use.